# How to manipulate files stored in S3 without saving them to the server?

Tags: python, web-services, amazon-s3, web-applications, boto3

I have the following python script that downloads two files from an S3 compatible service. Then merges them and uploads the output to another bucket.

```
import time
import boto3
import pandas as pd

timestamp = int(time.time())

conn = boto3.client('s3')
conn.download_file('segment', 'segment.csv', 'segment.csv')
conn.download_file('payment', 'payments.csv', 'payments.csv')

paymentsfile = 'payments.csv'
segmentsfile = 'segment.csv'
outputfile = 'payments_merged_' + str(timestamp) + '.csv'

csv_payments = pd.read_csv(paymentsfile, dtype={'ID': float})
csv_segments = pd.read_csv(segmentsfile, dtype={'ID': float})
csv_payments = csv_payments.merge(csv_segments, on='ID')
open(outputfile, 'a').close()
csv_payments.to_csv(outputfile)

conn.upload_file(outputfile, backup, outputfile)
```

However if I execute the script it stores the files in the folder of my script. For security reasons I would like to prevent this to happen. I could delete the files after the script was executed but let's assume my script is located in the folder `/app/script/`. This means for a short time, while the script is being executed, someone could open the url `example.com/app/script/payments.csv` and download the file. What is a good solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, pandas.read_csv let you read a buffer or byte object. You can do everything in the memory. Either put this script in a instance, even better,  you can run it as AWS lambda process if the file is small.

```
import time
import boto3
import pandas as pd

paymentsfile = 'payments.csv'
segmentsfile = 'segment.csv'
outputfile = 'payments_merged_' + str(timestamp) + '.csv'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
payment_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='payment', Key=paymentsfile )
segment_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='segment', Key=segmentsfile )

csv_payments = pd.read_csv(payment_obj['Body'], dtype={'ID': float})
csv_segments = pd.read_csv(segments_obj['Body'], dtype={'ID': float})
csv_merge = csv_payments.merge(csv_segments, on='ID')
csv_merge.to_csv(buffer)
buffer.seek(0)

s3.upload_fileobj(buffer, 'bucket_name', outputfile )
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to modify the configuration of your web server to not serve the directory that you are writing to or write to a directory that isn't served. For example, a common practice is to use /scr for this type of thing. You would need to modify permissions for the user your web server runs under to ensure it has access to /scr.

To restrict web server access to the directory you write to you can use the following in Nginx -

https://serverfault.com/questions/137907/how-to-restrict-access-to-directory-and-subdirs

For Apache you can use this example -

https://serverfault.com/questions/174708/apache2-how-do-i-restrict-access-to-a-directory-but-allow-access-to-one-file-w

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean my app that is controlled by a user interface will be able to write into that folder but nobody else will be able to access it?

Comment: Yes, by modifying your web server config your running code can access it but it will not be served to end users.